# Knockout not binding multiple spans?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js to bind my view model to my view.

Weirdly, the bindings don't seem to work properly and I have no clue why.

```
<table class="matches" data-bind="visible: matches().length > 0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Details</th>
                <th>Customer Details 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: matches">
            <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToCustomerMatching">
                <td data-bind="with: customer">
                    <p>
                        <b data-bind="text: description" />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine1" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine2" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine3" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine4" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: postcode" /><br />
                        <i>(<span data-bind="text: customerAccountNumber" />)</i>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="with: match">
                    <p>
                        <b><!--ko text: customerCode--><!--/ko--></b><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine1" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine2" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine3" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine4" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: addressLine5" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: postcode" /><br />
                        <span data-bind="text: domain" />
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

`matches` is an `observableArray`.

The first binding works, and the description is displayed (twice!?)
The remaining bindings fail, and the HTML isn't even generated.

However, when using the container-less markup (the html comments) for the first binding, the first AND second bindings work. You can see this in the second column.

[image: Screenshot]

I really don't understand why this is happening, and I don't want to have to use the container-less markup for everything, so any ideas would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this is a problem, as the only reference I found to this solution was for an irrelevant problem to do with whitespace on old versions of IE. I tested on Chrome and on Firefox, so....

I found that using an explicitly opened and closed tag worked.
E.g.

```
<b data-bind="text: description"></b>
```

worked, but

```
<b data-bind="text: description"/>
```

didn't.

Any clues as to why would be appreciated :)